# Mist models/Mesa installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, astronomy

Currently trying to read a .eep file on python. When I try to call the function read_mist_models, the following error shows:

```
 import read_mist_models 
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'read_mist_models'
```

Any suggestions? Tried downloading MESA, cannot figure out how to download ndiff since its required before mesa installation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No, I think i don't have the proper prerequisites installed on my computer. I tried downloading mesa, but it says I need to install 'ndiff' first, and when I try and do that it says "configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables"

Comment: I ran into the same problem, if ndiff is not recognized it means that the sdk was not initialized properly, it turned out for me that I was getting this error because I was using the wrong distribution of the mesasdk for macos. I'm still running into other errors but this could be one problem for you. Try deleting the sdk and reinstalling it for whatever system you're on

Comment: Turns out there are very specific versions of sdk for each mesa verison. you want to be careful to download the proper verisons that are compatible with one another. I'm still running into errors but this has gotten me further